# show $ \|\,|A|\,\|_2 \le \sqrt n\|A\|_2 $ for $ m \ge n $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

how can I go about showing that $ \||A|\|_2 \le \sqrt n\|A\|_2 $ when $m$ (rows)$ \ge n $ (columns)

$|A| $ denotes the absolute value of  $ |A_{ij}|$ for all $i,j$.

The only thing I can think of is using the matrix norm induced by vector norm definition but apart from that I'm pretty clueless on how to proceed/complete the proof. I get:

$\|\,|A|\,\|_2= \sup \dfrac{\|\,|A|\,x\|_2}{\|x\|_2} $ for $ x \neq0 $

Comment: You have two norms to compare, one probably an induced operatornorm, the largest singular value, and if I had to guess, the second the Frobeniusnorm, i.e., the norm for the scalar product $<A,B>=trace(B^TA)$. Can you confirm and identify?

Comment: Then please define what the norm in the right side is.

Comment: But is that not, by your own post, the triple striped norm on the left? Alternativly you have to explain what $|A|$ is here.

Comment: What is the absolute value of a matrix?

Comment: Not to mention: what are $m$ and $n$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you get
$$
\|\,|A|\,\|_2\le \|A\|_F:=\sqrt{\sum_{ij}|A_{ij}|^2}
$$
as
$$
\|\,|A|\,x\|_2\le\sum_{j=1}^n\|\,|A|\,e_i\|_2·|x_i|
\le\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\|\,|A|\,e_i\|_2^{\;2}}·\|x\|_2=\|A\|_F·\|x\|_2
$$
Then the classical norm equivalence estimate is
$$
\|A\|_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\|Ae_i\|_2^{\;2}
\le\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\|A\|_2·\|e_i\|_2\right)^2
= n\|A\|_2^{\,2}.
$$

---

One can also cut out the middle man Frobenius and combine both steps as
\begin{align}
\|\,|A|\,x\|_2
&\le\sum_{j=1}^n\|\,|A|\,e_i\|·|x_i|
   =\sum_{j=1}^n\|A\,e_i\|_2·|x_i|
\\&\le\sum_{j=1}^n\|A\|_2\|e_i\|_2·|x_i| 
=\|A\|_2\|x\|_1\le\sqrt{n}\|A\|_2\|x\|_2
\end{align}